# Degree Polynomials and Zeroes

Tags: polynomials, roots

"Find a degree $3$ polynomial that has zeros $-3, 4$ and $8$ and in which the coefficient of $x^2$ is $-18$."

I've been trying to solve this problem, but I keep getting it wrong. I've worked with other problems in which the highest degree of the polynomial is given a coefficient, and looked up examples for this one, but can't figure out a way to apply what I've learned to solve this problem.

Steps Done:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x+3)(x-4)(x-8)\\  
f(x) &= (x^2-x-12)(x-8)\\ 
f(x) &= a(x^3-7x^2-4x+96)
\end{align}
**Side Note**
When I solved for "a", I ended up with "a = 2.57", but it says that that isn't the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost entirely correct.

Certainly, the polynomial will be some constant multiple of $f(x) = (x+3)(x-4)(x-8)$.  It seems you've made one tiny error, however.  Multiplying this out, the coefficient on $x^2$ should be $-9$, and not $-7$.

From there, you just solve $-9a = -18$, which unfortunately you were trying to do with the wrong coefficient.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Thanks, I couldn't figure out where I was going wrong. So I have the general steps down, right?

Comment: Absolutely!  It looks like you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The cubics that have the desired roots have the shape $k(x+3)(x-4)(x-8)$.

Note that the sum of the roots of $(x+3)(x-4)(x-8)$ is $9$, so the coefficient of $x^2$ is $-9$.  We want it to be $-18$, so we must take $k=2$.